# jQuery $.inArray returns -1 when it should be 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hell All,

I have an odd problem:

```js
//dataText hold current language data that's gathered from another function
//pick one to test it out
//if english data gathered
var dataText = ["Data uploads"];
//if french data gathered
var dataText = ["Envois de données"];

function lang_lib(lang) {   
    var data_fre = [13, 'Envois de données'];
    var data_eng = [14, 'Data uploads'];
    var data_lang, rep_lang;

    switch(lang) {
        case "English":
            data_lang = data_eng;
            data_rep = rep_eng;
            break;
        case "Français":
            data_lang = data_fre;
            data_rep = rep_fre;
            break;
        default:
            $('table.infobox tbody').append('<tr><td id="lang-fail"><ul class="first last"><li>User language is not available</li></ul></td></tr>');
    };

    this.data_uploads = data_lang[1];
}
_lang = new lang_lib($('#toplinks-language').text());

//if lang_lib("English")
alert($.inArray(_lang.data_uploads, dataText)); // 0

//if lang_lib("Français")
alert($.inArray(_lang.data_uploads, dataText)); // -1
```

I shortened the code but it should give a general idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

I know it seems weird why I would be using the same data in two arrays but the data_fre and data_eng have language specific dataText info plus other language specific data as well. dataText will have non-specific language data which is why I'm testing it agains data_fre or data_eng to find which language to use.

I can't figure out why it would return -1 because I have other languages set (with special character too like Russian text) and they all return 0.

Appreciate the help :)

Comment: also check if _lang.data_uploads is not null.. can you host it on jsfiddle?

Comment: maybe it has something to do with the c-cedilla in Français?

Comment: i would try using Fran&ccedil;ais instead of Français, in both your html and your function.

Comment: dataText is actually above the function and the data inside the array changes based on language. I'll update the main post to give a clearer view.

Comment: Are you certain that your language is being set correctly if it is Francais?  Try alerting _lang.data_lang.length.

Comment: @pixeline That doesn't seem to be the problem. It's selecting the correct language.

Comment: @JohnGreen When I alert _lang.data_uploads it shows: Envois de données

Comment: Wait a second... dataText is *ALWAYS* "Envois de données" in that code.  Any which way, I built a fiddle for you to play with.  It all works the way it is supposed to, as long as you're not double-writing dataText:  http://jsfiddle.net/edd6T/

Comment: @JohnGreen I fixed it but if you are curious I signed up for jsfiddle and added the full code with the original error [jsfiddle.net/rXM9k](http://jsfiddle.net/rXM9k)

Comment: @RVCA18 - I looked at it too.  Figured out that you had an extra space, and was about to tell you so when I noticed in the comments the bit about the trim.  This is why printf/alert debugging generally doesn't work.  You view the string representation of the object instead of the object itself.  Highly recommend using Chrome-Inspect/Firefox-Firebug for debugging.

Comment: @JohnGreen Where would I see that in Chrome Inspect?

Comment: Add a console.log where you were using Alert.  You'll get much better results, including full object patterning.  Note that you can't keep that in production code, as it will cause script errors in other browsers.  There are ways around that, but it is generally best to just not use that kind of output when you go final.

Comment: @JohnGreen Cool thanks :) tried it out. I was only using alerts to try to pinpoint where something went wrong, but the console.log is so much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out what it was.

I used `$.trim()` in the function that collects data for dataText. Since I couldn't see any leading or trailing spaces when I would `alert()` it was confusing me why it wouldn't work.

This explains why `$.inArray()` wouldn't match "Envois de données" with "Envois de données ".

Thanks again everybody for taking a look :)

Answer (score 2):

-1 means false.  0 means 'at position 0'.  Without knowing more about the data coming in, I expect it is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Strings do not match numbers.

Simple Test

```
var arr = [13, 'Envois de données'];    
console.log($.inArray(13,arr));    // 0 - matches as a number
console.log($.inArray("13",arr));  // -1 - matches as a string
```

Comment: I'm not trying to match the numbers though.